# Can not convert some SQL time formats

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, time

I have a strange problem and I don't know why this happens. I have some Listboxes and a DataGridView. One can select multiple elements in the Listboxes (multiple in one Listbox or in multiple Listboxes) - Each Listbox represents a column in my database and represents the users choice in the DataGridView. Now when I select a dateformat (column: delivery date) I do a SELECT Statement. That works even when I select multiple dates in this Box (OR Statement). When selecting dates in a Listbox and another element in a different Box it's a SELECT Statement with AND - for example:

```
SELECT [...] FROM [...] WHERE (Customer_Id='0061') AND(Delivery_Date='01.10.2013')
```

The AND Statements just work till the date 12.XX.XXXX. Then it crashes with an out of range exception and tells me varchar can not be formated to datetime. But when I have multiple dates selected and other elements from other Listboxes (OR and AND statement) it works... What is this?

I read the values from my Listbox and put them into an Array. Then I format them and copy the formated values into another array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < timeElementsUnformated.Count; i++)
        {
            formatTime = timeElementsUnformated[i];
            formatTime2 = formatTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
            timeElements.Add(formatTime2);
        }
```

Now I just read the elements from the array to build the SQL Statements and write:

```
 "(convert(varchar(10),Delivery_Date,104)='"
```

What's wrong? I hope I could describe the problem understandable

EDIT:
Here is the AND concatenation

```
  if (filteredValues.Count > 1)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < filteredValues.Count; j++)
            {
                partialANDstatement = " AND" + "(" + filteredValues[j] + ")";
                finalANDstatement = finalANDstatement + partialANDstatement;

            }

            finalANDstatement2 = "(" + filteredValues[0] + ")" + finalANDstatement;
```

Comment: Why do you use two format: dd/MM/yyyy and dd.MM.yyyy ? In general for SQL yyyy-MM-dd always works.

Comment: The one format is for DateTime in C# I think or am I wrong?

Comment: How are those dates connected in SQL ?

Comment: In SQL its date. I load them directly in the checkboxes and use the format (dd/MM/yyy) to read them in C# and convert them to String. To display them back in SQL I have to convert them again to read them as String and display them in my DataGridView. I'm just wondering why it works partially

Comment: Because you said that it works till 12th, that sounds like that month and day are mixed up somewhere. How do you generate the sql code from the array timeElements, that specific part where you generate the where clause, I am interested.

Comment: Ah ok. I save all my elements in different Arrays (one array for a listbox). Then I loop if there are multiple elements and concatenate each one of a list box with "OR" so that I have OR-Statements saved in a string (again one for every list box). When there are multiple Listboxes clicked I go again through a loop and concatenate these OR-Statements with AND's so that at the end a normal SQL statement is ready.

Comment: Can you show the constructed SQL code and how you constructed it?

Comment: Probably your code is expecting date in format dd.mm.yyyy where as database is returning in format mm.dd.yyyy.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your code is expecting date in format dd.mm.yyyy where as database is returning in format mm.dd.yyyy. That's why breaking after 12.XX.XXXX.

Use same format across app & DB preferably YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: I don't know. How to handle this? It works for normal statements and OR statements. When I format in SQL I use "104" - that's the one I need (DD.MM.YYYY)

Comment: Try using flags 101 or 103 and update the app code accordingly. SELECT convert(datetime, '10/23/2016',          101) -- mm/dd/yyyy       SELECT convert(datetime, '23/10/2016',          103) -- dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value. That happens only if ONE date value behind 12 is clicked and then another value from another listbox

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DbParameters` and `DateTime` data type directly. So, there are no need to convert your `DateTime` value to `string`.
For example:

```
var command = new SqlCommand("select * from YourTable where SomeDate = @SomeDate"));
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DateEnd", someDateTimeValue));
```